# Random Forest Interpretation

Tags: random-forest

I've run a Random Forest in R: fit.rf.
All I want to know is:
When I type 'fit.rf' the output shows '% var explained'
Is the % Var explained the **out of bag** variance explained?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes %variance explained(regression) and classification-error(class.) are OOB cross-validated. The exact formula, is not that well documented, but can be found in the print method.

Below is shown how you can inspect the print method for S3 model objects of class "randomForest"

```
library(randomForest)
aFunctionCopy = randomForest:::print.randomForest
fix(aFunctionCopy)
print(aFunctionCopy)
```

...and here a link to previous related [questions and answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/144700/negative-r2-at-random-regression-forest/144730#144730)